# Make API request with Access Token and Refresh

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin

I have a class that makes API requests for a mobile app. The code can be making multiple API requests at the same time. But, if the request is unauthorized, I want to refresh the access token. While the refresh is occurring, I do not want another process to try to refresh the token.

I think there should be a better way to keep other processes from refreshing the token while another process is refreshing the token.

The `TTSecureStorage` class is a wrapper around the Xamarin Essentials Secure Storage where I can store values using the devices Secure Storage.

```
namespace TTAzureClient
{
    public class AuthenticationDelegator : DelegatingHandler
    {
        public static string Token;
        private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        private static bool isReauthenticating = false;

    public object UserUtilities { get; private set; }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        // Clone the request, in case we need to re-issue it
        var clone = await CloneHttpRequestMessageAsync(request);
        try
        {
            string authToken = await TTSecureStorage.TokenStorage.GetAccessToken();

            clone.Headers.Remove("X-ZUMO-AUTH");
            clone.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
            var response = await base.SendAsync(clone, cancellationToken);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                TTSecureStorage.TokenStorage.RemoveAll();
                TTSecureStorage.UserDetailStorage.RemoveAll();
                var refreshToken = await TTSecureStorage.TokenStorage.GetRefreshToken();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
                {
                    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                    string newToken = await TTSecureStorage.TokenStorage.GetAccessToken();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newToken))
                    {
                        await RefreshToken();
                    }
                    authToken = await TTSecureStorage.TokenStorage.GetAccessToken();
                    semaphore.Release();

                    clone.Headers.Remove("Authorization");
                    clone.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
                    response = await base.SendAsync(clone, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clone a HttpRequestMessage
    /// Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044166/how-to-clone-a-httprequestmessage-when-the-original-request-has-content
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="req">The request</param>
    /// <returns>A copy of the request</returns>
    public static async Task<HttpRequestMessage> CloneHttpRequestMessageAsync(HttpRequestMessage req)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage clone = new HttpRequestMessage(req.Method, req.RequestUri);

        // Copy the request's content (via a MemoryStream) into the cloned object
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        if (req.Content != null)
        {
            await req.Content.CopyToAsync(ms).ConfigureAwait(false);
            ms.Position = 0;
            clone.Content = new StreamContent(ms);

            // Copy the content headers
            if (req.Content.Headers != null)
                foreach (var h in req.Content.Headers)
                    clone.Content.Headers.Add(h.Key, h.Value);
        }


        clone.Version = req.Version;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> prop in req.Properties)
            clone.Properties.Add(prop);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in req.Headers)
            clone.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);

        return clone;
    }

    private async Task<bool> RefreshToken()
    {
        try
        {
            string refresh_token = await TTSecureStorage.TokenStorage.GetRefreshToken();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_b2c_tt_ropc");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.BaseAddress);
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("grant_type", "refresh_token");
            dict.Add("resource", "<resource id>");
            dict.Add("client_id", "<client id>");
            dict.Add("response_type", "id_token");
            dict.Add("refresh_token", refresh_token);
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
            var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
            JsonSerializer json = new JsonSerializer();
            if (result.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var exMsg = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                try
                {
                    dynamic e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(exMsg);
                    //throw new MsalException(e.error, e.error_description);
                }
                catch (Exception exi)
                {
                    //throw new Exception(exMsg);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            var msg = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic ar = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(msg);

            //UserUtilities.token = ar.access_token;
            //UserUtilities.userAzureId = ar.id_token;

            Utils.Settings.Current.AuthToken = ar.access_token;
            Utils.Settings.Current.AzureMobileUserId = ar.id_token;
            Utils.Settings.Current.RefreshToken = ar.refresh_token;

            try
            {
                TokenStorage.RemoveAll();
                await TokenStorage.SetAccessToken(Convert.ToString(ar.access_token));
                await TokenStorage.SetIdToken(Convert.ToString(ar.id_token));
                await TokenStorage.SetRefreshToken(Convert.ToString(ar.refresh_token));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}